# Storyboarding ViewController.m

Tags: ios, xcode, segue, uistoryboardsegue, xcode-storyboard

I did an experiment in viewDidLoad where I put:

```
NSLog(@"The View did load :-) %@", self.title);
```

inside of viewDidLoad.... so each time I segue'd to my different views I watched the output change but I'm lost in the "conceptual" groundwork of things.

Where do I put my code for each view?  Xcode gives me the one ViewController.m, but shouldn't I create a separate ViewController.m for each view that I have in my storyboard and then each view has its own viewDidLoad?

I just watched the WWDC video on Segues/Storyboarding and going to play around with prepareForSegue:sender: to pass data between my views.  None of the books I have touch on Storyboarding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create separate controller for each View and than connect them from interface builder, When you will add ViewController in side your project...you will find them inside a drop box next to class in below images. So just select view and than select a red cycled tab and than assign a view controller for that view :)

**Visual**

[image]

Same with other views,

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! that was easy.  I just duplicated the ViewController.m and .h and renamed them ViewControllerMain.... and put it in NSLog that says "You are at the MAIN view" works great.  And easy -- pull down the menu and select the new class.  Glad to know it wasn't a CONTROL-*click* Much thanks for the answer.

Comment: got the green tick - see I AM NEW !! hahah ok now i'm catching on to the green check box.  :-)